# My Rails app is not saving data to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms

I am currently creating a rails form. Up until now it has been passing data to the database with ease. Recently, however it no longer finds any of the data I need in the database, it can only find the user table and none of the connected tables.

Here is a partial of my form:

```html
<h1>Energy Assistance Application</h1>
<br />

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'county_fields', f: f%>

  <%= render 'contact_info_fields', f: f %>

  <%= render 'household_members_fields', f: f%>

  <%= render 'household_type_fields', f: f%>
```

Here is part of my controller:

```rb
  def create
    addresses = params[:addresses].permit([:county]).to_h
    contact_info = params[:contact_info].permit(params[:contact_info].keys).to_h
    household = params[:household_type].permit([:house_type]).to_h
    household_members = member_params
    utilities = utility_params
    dhis = dhi_params
    @workflow = CreatesUser.new(address_info: addresses,
      contact: contact_info, household: household, members: household_members, utilities: utilities, dhis: dhis)
    @workflow.create
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

CreatesUser:

```rb
  def initialize(address_info: [], has_mail: false, contact: [], household: [], members: [],
      utilities: [], dhis: [])
    @address_info = address_info
    @contact = contact
    @household = household
    @members = members["household_members_attributes"]
    @utilities = utilities["utilities_attributes"]
    @dhis = dhis["dhis_attributes"]
  end

  def build
    self.user = User.new(startdate: Time.zone.today)
    user.addresses = get_addresses
    user.contact_info = get_contact
    user.household_type = get_household
    user.household_members = get_members
    user.utilities = get_utilities
    user.dhis = get_dhis
    user
  end

  def create
    build 
    result = user.save
    result ? print("Saved!\n") : print("Failed!\n")
  end
```

My index.html.erb:

```html
<h1>All Users</h1>
<% @users.each do |user|%>
  <%= user.utilities%>
  <ul>
    <li>County: 
      <% user.addresses.each do |address|%>
        <%=address.county%>
      <%end%>
    </li>
    <% if !user.contact_info.nil? %>   
      <li>Phone: <%= user.contact_info.phone%></li>
      <li>Phone Type:<%= user.contact_info.phone_type%></li>
      <li>Email: <%= user.contact_info.email%></li>
    <%end%>
    <li>Household: <%= user.household_type.house_type%></li>  
  </ul>
```

When the workflow creates, it saves successfully, but when I run my index I get this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `house_type' for nil:NilClass):
    12:       <li>Phone Type:<%= user.contact_info.phone_type%></li>
    13:       <li>Email: <%= user.contact_info.email%></li>
    14:     <%end%>
    15:     <li>Household: <%= user.household_type.house_type%></li>  
    16:   </ul>
    17: 
    18:   <h3> Household Members </h3>

app/views/users/index.html.erb:15:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___590344624549979162_70244223831340'
```

I do not know why this is happening, even when I go back to older branches that used to work, they also fail here.
Thank you for any help you can give me. If you need more info, I will happily give it to you.

Comment: Could you add your User model (at least the relationships part).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems in your form. Recheck your params ( household_type ), it must have a value when submit.

And another way, if you want update difference model based on current model, you should use [Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)